# How does Xcode handle multiple imports of the same files?

Tags: xcode, import

At my current workplace everything is capsulated into libraries.
These libraries often import the same files, because they have similar dependencies.

When I build an app while using three of these libraries everything works fine (on the surface level). Meaning no errors / duplicate complains, but I am interested in the build process here. Does Xcode realize that Exceptions.swift is there three times hidden inside those libraries and just uses it once for the build process? Or are we just generating loads of junk data? And if so how do other companies handle that?

Comment: It can detect the signature of the packages and use the already running one if needed. Also, it adds a namespace to the different parts so there would be no conflicts at all.